# The variable player of FollowPlayer has not been assigned You probably need to assign the player variable of the FollowPlayer script in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was just making a game in unity and watching a tutorial from youtube. When all of a sudden an error in the console said

> "The variable player of FollowPlayer has not been assigned You probably need to assign the player variable of the FollowPlayer script in the inspector."

How do you fix it?

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(player.position);
    }
}
```

And the other c# file has some code in it, it might have something to do with the error.

Second c# code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{ public Rigidbody rb;



    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); 

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity "Unassigned Reference Exception"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703244/unity-unassigned-reference-exception)

Comment: Nope. Not really.

Comment: Drag in the player object to the feild `player` on `FollowPlayer` in the inspector

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what that means.

Comment: Can you give me the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FollowPlayer has a public varaible.

The inspector of `FollowPlayer` object will have a field in the inspector where you can give this variable a value.

[image: Empty inspector field]

Drag your player object from the scene hirarchy into this field.

[image: Filled inspector field]

This will assign a reference of the object in your scene to your public variable.